# Setting different significant digits on manual colorbar tick labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-xarray

I am trying to manually set colorbar tick labels, but have the different labels have different significant digits. The current tick labels are `[0.001, 0.200, 0.500, 1.000, 1.500, 2.000]` but I want them to be `[0.001, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0]`. I am doing this with xarray plotting. My relevant code for this problem is as follows:

`prect_c` is a `xarray.DataArray` with size `{tag: 40, lat: 96, lon: 144}`

```
figp = plt.figure(figsize=(10., 10.), dpi=300.)
axp = figp.add_subplot(111, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

prect_c[tag, :, :].plot.contourf(
    ax=axp,
    transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
    cmap=cmaps.cmp_haxby_r,
    levels=np.insert(np.arange(0., 2.1, 0.1), 1, 0.001),
    add_colorbar=True,
    add_labels=False,
    extend='max',
    cbar_kwargs={
        'orientation': 'horizontal',
        'shrink': 0.8,
        'pad': 0.08,
        'label': 'mm/day',
        'ticks': [0.001, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0],
    },
)
```

[image]

I tried `'ticks': [0.001, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0]` and expected the significant digits to remain as I typed, but instead all significant digits default based on the value `0.001`.

Answer (score 0):

All the arguments to `cbar_kwargs` are passed to [`matplotlib.figure.Figure.colorbar`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.colorbar). From the docs:

> **ticks** : *None or list of ticks or Locator*
> If None, ticks are determined automatically from the input.
>
> **format** : *None or str or Formatter*
> If None, ScalarFormatter is used. Format strings, e.g., "%4.2e" or "{x:.2e}", are supported. An alternative Formatter may be given instead.

When you pass in `ticks`, you (correctly) use floats to specify the tick values. But floats in python do not have a specific format - in python, `0.2` is identical in every way to `0.20000` - they're the same object.

To specify the formatter to use, pass in the `format` argument. The simplest formatter, which will work in the cases you provide, is the default string formatter, `"{}".format`, e.g.:

```py
prect_c[tag, :, :].plot.contourf(
    ax=axp,
    transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
    cmap=cmaps.rainbow,
    levels=np.insert(np.arange(0., 2.1, 0.1), 1, 0.001),
    add_colorbar=True,
    add_labels=False,
    extend='max',
    cbar_kwargs={
        'orientation': 'horizontal',
        'shrink': 0.8,
        'pad': 0.08,
        'label': 'mm/day',
        'ticks': [0.001, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0],
        'format': "{}".format,
    },
)
```

For more options, see the matplotlib docs on [Tick Formatters](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks/tick-formatters.html).

Comment: Thank you! Adding 'format': '{}'.format solved this problem.